Is my prayer accepted if I'm wearing a thong underneath?
I started wearing thongs to please my husband. I also wear them underneath my modest clothes to hide the lines of underwear showing. I keep it the whole day and remove it at night.
If I'm completely dressed but I have a thong underneath during the prayer, is my prayer accepted? Is this considered not modest?

Good thing you’re not wearing socks with holes in them—then you’d really be in trouble!

Your prayer is accepted,  as long as your outer clothing is sufficiently modest and covers your `awrah during the prayer (which for a woman is typically the entire body except for the face, hands,), the type of underwear you're wearing underneath does not affect the prayer itself. The thong is considered private and hidden, so it is not an issue for your prayer.
As long as your clothing covers your `awrah and is not see-through you are dressed modestly.

Use the formatting tools provided! There have been multiple low-quality answers from you; you might as well take the hint.
